# Android: issues after updating SDK manager

Tags: android

I lately updated my Android SDK manager and since then my android went koo koo.
I manage to fix most of the problems but 2 of them are still exists:

1. when I run the SDK Manager.exe I get "Some packages were found but are not compatible updates" message under "Available Packages"-> android repository
2. under "Available Packages"-> third party add-ons   I see some existing updates but when I update them they are still there.

Did anyone bumped with this issue? how can I fix it?

thanks
-Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not worry about your 1st problem. It is common possibly some older non-compatible/outdated repository exists on server and you do not need this anyway.
Second problem is a bug found and as many times you download and update they remain there. It may be resolved eventually. But you need not download again and again same thing. Infact I got that third party add-ons added 2 times in my installed list and again was showing in available items. So you already have that 3rd party addon installed and you can test by creating an avd with it.

Comment: In other words I have nothing to do except waiting for the next SDK Manager update?

Comment: Yes .. but this should not give any problems for development AFAIK.